# Logic Issue A or C (C and B)

Tags: java, logic, operation

ive got the following code for a drag and drop event:

```
if (event.getType().equals("mousedown")){
    isMouseDown = true;
}

if (event.getType().equals("mouseup")){
    isMouseDown = false;
}

if (event.getType().equals("mouseout")){
    isMouseDown = false;
}

if (event.getType().equals("mousemove")){
    if (isMouseDown)
        thisMove(event);    
}
```

how can i shorten this now with a better logic i tried

```
isMouseDown = event.getType().equals("mousedown") && !(event.getType().equals("mousemove") && isMouseDown);

if (event.getType().equals("mousemove") && isMouseDown)
    thisMove(event);
```

but its wrong...

Comment: A switch will probably be better than a long logic expression.

Comment: would be a switch in this case "professional"?

Comment: Yes, a switch is what you want to do @user3369579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code as follow:

```
   switch(event.getType()){
        case "mousedown":
            isMouseDown = true;
            break;
        case "mouseup":
        case "mouseout":
            isMouseDown=false;
            break;
        case "mousemove":
            if(isMouseDown)  thisMove(event);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Good answer. Note: if you are going to leave it empty anyways, you can remove the `default` clause altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a switch statement like the following:

```
switch(event.getType()) {
    case "mousedown":
        code block
        break;
    case "mouseup":
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use default value and one if as below :

```
isMouseDown = false;
if (event.getType().equals("mousedown"))
{
    isMouseDown = true;
}
if (event.getType().equals("mousemove"))
{
     if (isMouseDown)
           thisMove(event);
}
```

I know switch would be a better option. But just in case.....

Comment: better write ("mousedown".equals("vent.getType())

Comment: "mousedown" is never null. So you ll never have NPE and it is still false if vent.getType() is null.

Comment: in your code, `thisMove(event)` will never be executed because `isMouseDown` is false when the program control gets inside `if (event.getType().equals("mousemove"))`.

Comment: @d_air , why would it be false if the mousedown event occurs? isn't it what the OP wants. it should only be true in case on mousedown and false otherwise? I just made it false initially and made it true only if mousedown occured...

Comment: @Codeek If the mousemove event occurs, the `isMouseDown` variable is false since the program control won't execute the statement `isMouseDown = true;`. In the OP's logic, if mousemove event occurs, it is possible that `isMouseDown` is true depending on it's old value. So the OP's code have the chance of executing the `thisMove(event)`.

Comment: hmmm... that is a chance.... I had thought about it earlier.. but then I just took into consideration three checks that OP made in her/his post. anyways... Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep track of state (`isMouseDown` in your case) it is generally easier (and better) to encapsualte that state in an object along with the functionality that makes use of that state.

```
class Mouse {

    boolean down = false;

    public void event(Event event) {
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case MouseDown:
                down = true;
                break;
            case MouseUp:
            case MouseOut:
                down = false;
                break;

            case MouseMove:
                if (down) {
                    thisMove(event);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static class Event {

    enum Type {

        MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseOut;
    }

    public Event() {
    }

    private Type getType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still write the code in a similar way you originally you wrote it. Here's the logic.

```
    String t = event.getType();        
    isMouseDown = t.equals("mousedown") ||  !(t.equals("mouseup")) &&  !(t.equals("mouseout")) && isMouseDown;

    if (t.equals("mousemove") && isMouseDown)
        thisMove(event);
```

Comment: thanks thats it but i think a switch is in this case really the best solution

Comment: @user3369579 Yes I agree that switch is a better solution to this. And it's way easier to comprehend. I am just challenged by the logic of your question and your attempts to shorten the codes. So I offered a working code that is somewhat similar to your first attempt. Just in case you like it your way.